# Three AA batteries in series, only 1 depleted?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, esp8266

I am powering an ESP8266 with 3 rechargeable AA batteries. The ESP logs the voltage, so I saw the voltage getting lower over time. Much earlier than expected, the ESP stopped working since the voltage got too low. I measured the batteries afterwards and I noticed one of them had a really low voltage while the other two were fine (1.2v). What would cause only one cell to get depleted faster than the others? And how can that situation be avoided in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, I only use rechargeable batteries in series if they were all fully charged at the same moment. If one of them has been allowed to self-discharge for a while, then it could also be the first to collapse in use. Put them through a complete recharge cycle and test again (mark the special one beforehand.) If the same one collapses very early again, toss it. It's aged too much or wasn't made correctly in the first place.

Comment: Is te batteries of the same spec?

Comment: Same spec batteries. Could be they were charged on different times. Will try with another set, charged at the same time.

Comment: They key point is that you need to stop drawing current when the voltage of any cell drops.  Overdischarged NiMH cells will actually grow internal shorts if left connected, at which point a smart charger will refuse to touch them, but a couple second-long pulses from a non-detecting charger will often rescue them.

Comment: 1.2V is not 'ok-ish', it's almost empty.

Comment: To prevent this in the future, monitor individual cell voltages yourself, or you can use a [BMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_management_system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, one of your batteries is bad.  Or at least less good than the others.  In series, the current is the same through all cells.  So it is impossible for one cell to be drained faster than the others.  They are drained at exactly the same rate.  The problem is that one of the cells has less capacity than the others, so its voltage drops earlier.

Putting cells of any kind (rechargeable or primary) in series demands that the cells be well matched or have some sort of balancing circuitry integrated into the pack.

Basically, if you want to use multiple rechargeable AAs in series, they need to be the same brand, the same age, from the same pack, and should live and die together.  Charged together in series, depleted together in series, everything that happens to one cell happens to all the cells.

And even then, sometimes you'll just have a bad cell.

In this case, let's consider the current running through the cells in series.

It will always be the same current through all three cells.  If one is significantly lower voltage, that means that the effective capacity of that cell is less than the others.  And, in this application, for all intents and purposes, the capacity of the batteries is going to be the capacity of the weakest link in the chain, as the voltage drops too far otherwise.

How is it that one of the cells is delivering a lower capacity than the other two?  It could be any number of reasons.  Perhaps one is older, or has been used more.  Perhaps it is just a bad cell.  This can happen even when the batteries are new and all from the same pack.  It's not common, but it's also not exactly rare.

It is absolutely vital that you use well-matched cells when in a series application like this.  Fortunately, I don't think the ESP8266 can drain the cells enough to cause a reversal of a bad cell, but it is something to think about:

Let's say you are discharging 4 cells in series, and one of them has lost some of its capacity, for whatever reason.  The current will be the same through all the cells at all times.  But, your device is able to run off the voltage produced even by just 3 cells working and 1 cell totally dead.

What happens?

Well, the bad cell is going to be discharged below the minimum voltage it should be, further and further, all the way down to 0V.  If you measured the cells, there would be 0V across this cell.  However, since your device can keep running even with a dead cell, it continues drawing current.  At this point, current is actually going to be forced through the dead cell, but in the wrong direction (discharging).  This is cell reversal.  In low discharge rate applications, it usually damages or destroys the cell prematurely.  In high discharge rate applications, it can cause the bad cell to vent (explode).

Just be wary about batteries in series - you can't just mix and match rechargeable AAs in series, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: This is both impractically strict, and missing the most important point - which is that the actual issue is that with rechargeables is that you need to *stop drawing current* when the total pack voltage drops below the series count times the minimum voltage.  In a very high cell count pack it could be hard to detect one undervoltage cell that way, but with a mere three it's not complicated - when the voltage drops too low, shut it off and recharge.

Answer (score 1):

All cells in a good module are matched to within 1% of each other, and any difference in the initial matching amplifies towards the module end of life... you may have had only a 5% cell-match at module-creation which then caused an earlier end of life for the cell that failed.

The product of Ic=C*dV/dt implies that the smallest charge or the weakest cell dies first from overvoltage or undervoltage and lack of a BMS (battery management system), which would have prevented the overvoltage or undervoltage and prolonged the life of the weak cell and therefore your module.

Comment: BMS = battery management system. (Tony's very busy.)